# c++ const_cast question

Tags: c++

```
const int a = 1;
int *p = const_cast<int*>(&a);
*p = 2;
cout << “value a=”<< a << endl;
cout << “value *p=” <<*p << endl;
cout << “address a=” <<&a << endl;
cout << “address p=” <<p << endl;
```

output:

```
value a=1
value *p=2
address a=0xbff1d48c
address p=0xbff1d48c
```

WHY???
why same addr ,diff value?
confused.
thank you!

Comment: I like how it starts with BFF. :)

Comment: pedantic-errors to catch this mistake in the code!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In C++ language it is illegal to attempt to modify constant objects. Such an attempt results in undefined behavior.

In your program the `*p = 2` assignment attempts to modify a constant object `a`. The behavior is undefined. The weird output you observe is exactly that: undefined behavior.

There's no meaningful explanation for undefined behavior.

(Your compiler probably translated the `cout << a;` statement into `cout << 1;`, since the value of `a` cannot legally change. So, regardless of what you do to your `a`, `1` will always be printed.)

Comment: To add a practical reason: probably the const value was cached somewhere because it's const, whereas the other value wasn't. So you're seeing the real value, and the old value, cached. (This is just a guess.)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to AndreyT, you might be wondering that if editing a constant gives undefined behavior then why do we need `const_cast<>` ? The `const_cast<>` is meant for getting write privilege for the values **which are not write protected by birth**. Just try below changes and it should give proper behavior:

```
int b = 1;  // 'b' is modifiable
const int a = b;
...
```

Comment: Good point, though not the only one (e.g. `const_cast<>` can also be used to *add* `const` qualification).

Comment: @Tony: static_cast (and thus even implicit cast) can be used to _add_ `const` qualification. `const_cast` is designed specifically to _remove_ const qualification.

Comment: @Serge: yes `static_cast<>` *can* be used to add `const`, but if `const_cast<>` was only designed to remove it it wouldn't be capable of adding it ;-P. I do realise that some people prefer to use `static_cast<>` - have had that discussion on SO before - I continue to disagree with them. If you have a logical reason to prefer `static_cast<>`, rather than just an arbitrary assertion, please share it.

Comment: "if `const_cast<>` was only designed to remove it it wouldn't be capable of adding it" Why is that? `const_cast<>` provides the ability to change `const/volatile` qualification to any combination - it would be just unnatural to restrict to only removing qualifications. But using `const_cast` to add `const` is unsafe because you may accidentally remove `volatile` qualification. Besides it is both more natural and much simpler to leave implicit casts instead of explicitly writing `const_cast`.

Comment: @Serge: "unnatural to restrict to only removing" - while you say users - rather than the compiler - should restrict themselves?  ;-) In most applications `volatile` is hardly used, and where it is used it tends to be very deliberate and careful, so there's no practical likelihood of accidentally modifying it.  Implicit casts don't communicate expectations of the caller: consider `n = f(const_cast<const T>(x));`, here - the caller explicitly ensures f can't expect a non-`const` reference.  That's occasionally useful (e.g. `f` untrusted (from template param) + change to `x` corrupts state).

Comment: @Tony: So how `n = f(static_cast<const T>(x));` is worse than your const_cast-based expression? This expression have every advantage of your expression and none of its disadvantages. In addition writer/reader is absolutely sure that the cast is always safe in every way (because only static_cast is that safe).

Comment: @Serge: it's a misnomer... if you're adding or removing `const`, it's nice to use `const_cast<>`, which communicates that it's the constness that's at issue (given `volatile`'s hardly ever used) and not some other conversion you'd like to happen....

Comment: @Tony: Practically it is never relevant if you add constness or perform any other safe+fast/instant typecasting. For typecasting only two things may be relevant: (1) the final type with qualifiers you cast into and (2) confidence that the cast is safe - i.e. always legal and don't lead to performance penalty. Only `static_cast` gives second (a) without knowledge of the exact qualified type of the expression being cast and (b) for any final type. And `const_cast` seems more readable only if the reader has (or had) some illusions about its meaning.

Comment: @Serge: "it's not relevant if you add const"? Just because you might not have had occasion to care doesn't mean noone else has. "illusions" - i.e. anyone who doesn't do it your way's deluded. What an attitude!